# Switching Costs in a Multi-Modal Network Database in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, transportation, multimodal-network

I am constructing a multi-modal transportation network using Network Analysis on ArcGIS. I have data on roads, railway, and rivers for the U.S. My goal is to calculate an Origin-Destination matrix of the cost to transport goods from each U.S. county to each port along the U.S.'s coastline.

What I would like to model is the fixed cost of switching modes of transportation. For example, goods transported using roads would incur a fixed cost of $500 to switch to railway transportation. This fixed cost may include the cost for unloading the truck, storage in a warehouse until departure, and loading them on a train.

What would be the simplest way to include this fixed switching cost in a work database?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and the Network Analyst Extension.

Comment: It's been too long since I actually did it. I want to say it can be done either with a cost applied to that junction (in which case I'm not sure how you don't apply the cost if going straight through without changing modes), modeling turns and applying a specific cost to the turns on/off one mode to the other, or using point cost barriers (same issue as the first method). I'll have to refresh my memory if I get some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say very small links around rail/road intersection nodes will do

[image]

Comment: Remember to remove original node, so changing mode can happen through switch only